# Windows Phone Saving Data Existing Xml File

Tags: xml, windows-phone-8, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, isolatedstorage

I'm using xml file in my Windows Phone project. I need my project's data saving in existing xml file. And I using IsolatedStorage. But when emulator closing, my project data is missing. Now, I need to store my data when using IsolatedStorage. So, I saving my data in existing xml file when emulator is working. And, after closing the emulator, need to avoid the loss of my data. I mustn't use Isolated Storage. Is there a way it is? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you restart the emulator, the original environment is reloaded. It's pretty much like if you bought a new phone. Therefore, everything that you have saved locally will be lost. If you want to avoid that, the only way is to use some kind of remote storage (Skydrive for instance).

But keep in mind that this behavior occurs only with the emulator. When your application is deployed to a real device, the data you save in the isolated storage will be kept as long as the user doesn't uninstall your app. So you probably don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data on the phone the ONLY option is Isolated Storage. There is nowhere else you can store data files on the phone.

If you need to persist data across application installs then you'll need to store it remotely somewhere. (e.g. a webserver, sky drive, or any equivalents).